# How can the armature current of a DC shunt motor be zero at no-load?

Tags: electric-machine

I have seen the mathematical explanation of this explained using back EMF, where the back EMF would equal the input voltage and hence the armature current would be zero. But I'm unable to understand that if the armature current is zero at no-load for the motor then how can the motor shaft rotate with the maximum speed at this state ? (As there is no current flowing through the armature windings it shouldn't be able to rotate?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In 'imaginary world' the motor is armature is rotating freely without bearing friction or windage, so once it get up to speed (which takes forever, but it gets very close very quickly) it continues to rotate at exactly the RPM to counter the applied voltage. Since there is zero current, zero torque is produced (but none is needed to keep the rotor spinning).

If you subsequently reduce the voltage, the current flows in the opposite direction compared to starting up, and the rotor RPM drops. If you increase the voltage the motor RPM increases to balance the applied voltage with back EMF, as before.

In reality, the no-load current is not zero, but it's a lot less than the current at full load and much, much less than the current with rotor locked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I agree with Mr spehro's answer. That is Newton's 1st law.you can demonstrate this by using a simple 3v motor and 3v battary and current meter in series. When motor run fast see the current. Then lightly hold the armature rod by your hand giving it friction to slow. When the motor is slow current increase you can see from the AMMETER. When the motor runs fast the current is very low.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You measure the characteristics of the BEMF voltage so that the motor is rotated by another motor that is coupled on a shaft with tested motor. Also the torque VS speed can be measured with such setup, the tested motor is coupled with a generator.